# ctypes in python size with the `sys.getsizeof(Var)` method vs `ctypes.sizeof(Var)`

Tags: python, size, byte, ctypes, sys

I have a question about variable size in python, I'm using the the Ctypes because i want a 1 byte number, but when I tried to check it's size in python (via `sys.getsize`) it said it was 80 byte but when i checked with the ctypes (via `ctypes.sizeof`) it said it was 1 byte only, can someone tell me what is the difference and why is there 2 different sizes? is it because python is using an object or wrapper? and when its sent to c it views the real size?

```
import sys
import ctypes

print("size in ctypes is : ",ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_byte(1)))
print("size in sys is : ",sys.getsizeof(ctypes.c_byte(1)))
```

results in

```
size in ctypes is :  1
size in sys is :  80
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to know the details, you should take a look at [`objects.h`](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Include/object.h?revision=81029&view=markup) (especially the comments at the top of the file). Your `ctypes.c_byte(1)` is a Python object:

```
>>> import sys
>>> import ctypes
>>> isinstance(ctypes.c_byte(1), object)
True
```

As noted by @Daniel, `sys.getsizeof` gets the size of that Python object. That Python object is larger than the corresponding object in C. Note the following from the `object.h` comments:

```
Objects are structures allocated on the heap. . . .
The actual memory allocated for an object
contains other data that can only be accessed after casting the pointer
to a pointer to a longer structure type.  This longer type must start
with the reference count and type fields; the macro PyObject_HEAD should be
used for this.
```

In other words, a macro `PyObject_HEAD` is attached to the start of every object. This increases the size of the Python object.

`ctypes.sizeof`, on the other hand, returns the actual size of the `C` data type that is within the Python object (using C's `sizeof` operator).

**EDIT**

In light of your goal that you mention in your comment to Daniel's post, it is possible to send one byte over a server in Python 3.x. Below is an example of how you would send a byte using Python's `socket` module to prove this point.

Here is the server, which you will run in one Python interpreter:

```
# Server
import socket

HOST = ''                      # All available interfaces
PORT = 50007                   # Same port as client
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print('Connected by', addr)
while True:
    data = conn.recv(1)        # receive data with bufsize 1; a larger bufsize will break this code
    if not data: break
    conn.sendall(data)
conn.close()
```

Here is the client, which you will run in another python interpreter:

```
# Client
import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'             # The remote host, but here using localhost
PORT = 50007                   # The port used by both the client and server
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.sendall(b'1')                # a bytes object
data = s.recv(1)               # Receive data from the socket with bufsize of 1
s.close()
print('Received', repr(data))  # confirm receipt
```

Comment: yeah i guessed that this have happened as i mentioned an object wrapper, so only if it's passed to an actually C code it would count as the ctypes size?

Comment: @Newbie Yes, to a certain extent. I see your comment under Daniel's post, and you can attain your goal through Python 3.x. I'll update my post to show you how.

Comment: Thanks very much, i actually tried this before but it didn't work, must've had something wrong with my code since yours work perfectly :) thanks!

Comment: @Newbie Glad to help, and I'm glad you were thinking along the same lines. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

The ctypes module is used for creating and manipulating C data types in Python.
That is why ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_byte(1)) returns 1.

```
>>> import sys
>>> help(sys.getsizeof) Help on built-in function getsizeof in module sys:

getsizeof(...)
    getsizeof(object, default) -> int

    Return the size of object in bytes.
```

while

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> help(ctypes.sizeof)
Help on built-in function sizeof in module _ctypes:

sizeof(...)
    sizeof(C type) -> integer
    sizeof(C instance) -> integer
    Return the size in bytes of a C instance

>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

`sys.getsizeof` returns the size of a python object, this has nothing to do with the size of a C data type. And it is nothing you have to concern about.

Comment: i have an assignment and i'm supposed to send only 2 bytes via a UDP packet and it's kinda frustrating since i can't find a way to store just a couple of bytes in a variable, prolly shouldn't have chosen python for this type of assignment? but it's not possible that python can't achieve this task

Comment: How do you send your bytes? Just use a bytestring. ctypes is only for communicating with foreign libraries in other languages.